# Directx 9 compiling shaders at run time

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, directx

I've been getting into Directx programming lately. All is good for me, but there is one big issue. Each and every time I run the program, even when there hasn't been any changes to the code, it has to compile the shaders. Is there a way to set it so that it only has to compile them when they are edited?

It is rather annoying trying to perfect values to the way I want them when I have to wait 2 minutes every time I compile.

And yes, it is compiling them at run time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [fxc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb509710%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to precompile the shaders into .fxo files. These can be loaded by `D3DXCreateEffectFromFile` just like your .fx files. This should significantly decrease loading time.

See the [CompiledEffect Sample](http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/query/ee416326) from the SDK for details.

As a sidenote, are you *sure* it is the shader compiling that is causing the long delay? Large amounts of shaders definitely can cause a slowdown like that, but if you are ´getting into DirectX programming´ like you say... how many lines of shader code are we talking about?

Comment: Thanks. And when I run the program there is a popup box that says "Compiling shaders". And at this point I'm only messing around with the samples and trying to understand how everything works, those shaders can be rather large.